# How can I create a bidirectional bus using a 18F4550?

Tags: c, microcontroller, pic

Basically what Im trying to do its to use a single port of the PIC18F4550 as both inputs and outputs. Im going to connect a 7-segment-display to 7 pins of the port and with 4 pins of the same port. The four inputs are for introduce the numbers from 0 to 15 (F) in binary and the number in binary will represent in decimal in the display. Im using PIC C Compiler for the code.

**Update:** Following the first comment I modify the code and I think it is basically the same, I just read directly the input of the port B and use a switch-case in order to send the corresponding decimal number, also I added a default state so when I connected it should be a 0 in the display. Here it is the connection diagram, my teacher told me that I can ignore the logic gates but I'm not shure about that, in case I want to added I just need to use another port like port D to send a single high or low depending on how the port B is working.

**Update 2:** It finally work, it seems that the fact that I can ignore the logic gates it was partially true, the code was easier than I though, I just added a three port D high and low outputs to the EN and OE of both 74Ls244 and 74HC573 corresponding inputs so I can enable or disable depending on the port B state (output or input). Thank you all.
[image]

```
#include<18F4550.h>
#fuses XT, NOWDT, NOLVP, NOPROTECT, PUT
#use delay(clock = 4M, crystal = 8M)
#use fast_io(b)

void main(){

int8 INDSP;
int8 OUTDSP;


while(true){

  SET_TRIS_B(0xFF);
  INDSP = input_b()&0x0F;
  switch(INDSP){
     
     case 0b00000000:
        OUTDSP = 0x3F;
     break;
     
     case 0b00000001:
        OUTDSP = 0x0C;
     break;
     
     case 0b00000010:
        OUTDSP = 0x76;
     break;
     
     case 0b00000011:
        OUTDSP = 0x5E;
     break;
     
     case 0b00000100:
        OUTDSP = 0x4D;
     break;
     
     case 0b00000101:
        OUTDSP = 0x5B;
     break;
     
     case 0b00000110:
        OUTDSP = 0x7B;
     break;
     
     case 0b00000111:
        OUTDSP = 0x0E;
     break;
     
     case 0b00001000:
        OUTDSP = 0x7F;
     break;
     
     case 0b00001001:
        OUTDSP = 0x4F;
     break;
     
     case 0b00001010:
        OUTDSP = 0x6F;
     break;
     
     case 0b00001011:
        OUTDSP = 0x79;
     break;
     
     case 0b00001100:
        OUTDSP = 0x33;
     break;
     
     case 0b00001101:
        OUTDSP = 0x7C;
     break;
     
     case 0b00001110:
        OUTDSP = 0x73;
     break;
     
     case 0b00001111:
        OUTDSP = 0x63;
     break;
     
     DEFAULT:
        OUTDSP = 0x3F;
     break;
  }
     delay_ms(500);
     SET_TRIS_B(0x00);
     output_b(OUTDSP);
     delay_ms(500);
  }
}
```

Comment: Please provide a connection diagram / schematic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Caveat:* Not a total solution, but some suggestions ...

We can simplify your `main` as it has large amounts of replicated code:

```
void
main()
{

    SET_TRIS_B(0b00001111);
    DSPIN = input_b();

    while (true) {
        if ((DSPIN >= 0b00000000) && (DSPIN <= 0b00001111))
            DSPOUT = DSPIN;
        else
            DSPOUT = 0;

        delay_ms(1000);
        SET_TRIS_B(0b11111111);

        if ((DSPOUT >= 0) && (DSPOUT <= 15))
            output_b(DSPVALOR[DSPOUT]);
        else
            output_b(DSPVALOR[0]);

        delay_ms(1000);
    }
}
```

Now, given the top part of `main`:

```
SET_TRIS_B(0b00001111);
DSPIN = input_b();
```

The question I have is: should this be *inside* the `while` loop at the top???

Otherwise, there's *no* need for a loop as `DSPIN` and `DSPOUT` will remain constant.

---

**UPDATE:**

This is a total guess, but after cursorily looking at the datasheet ...

I think you're mixing up the value for the `TRIS` port. The *second* `set_tris_b` call should have `0b00000000` to set all bits for output (and *not* `0b11111111` as you have which sets all bits for input).

I'm not sure you can do this with a *single* 8 bit port. You need four bits for the input value. But, you need seven bits for output to the 7 segment display.

This adds up to more than 8 bits. So, I think you need *two* ports. Since you're using port "b", I presume there is a port "a".

You *may* be able to time division multiplex a given bit for input and output as you've done, but I think it's dicey and I don't know enough about the specifics of the 18F's ports to say for sure.

Here's refactored code that assumes a separate port "a":

```
void
main()
{

    while (true) {
        // set port B lower four bits for input
        SET_TRIS_B(0b00001111);

        // get input and mask off don't care bits
        DSPIN = input_b();
        DSPIN &= 0b00001111;

        if ((DSPIN >= 0b00000000) && (DSPIN <= 0b00001111))
            DSPOUT = DSPIN;
        else
            DSPOUT = 0;

        delay_ms(1000);

        // set port A pins for output
        SET_TRIS_A(0b00000000);

        if ((DSPOUT >= 0) && (DSPOUT <= 15))
            output_a(DSPVALOR[DSPOUT]);
        else
            output_a(DSPVALOR[0]);

        delay_ms(1000);
    }
}
```

But, *if* the 18F lets you change the tristate bits on the fly and you can connect *both* the input bit switches on bits 0-3 *and* the 7 segment output bits on bits 0-6, you can simply change all `*_a` calls into `*_b` calls.

---

**UPDATE #2:**

Upon further reflection [and, again, this is speculation], *if* the 18F allows *one* port to be switched back and forth repeatedly between input and output, the "duty cycle" in the above code is [probably] incorrect.

With 1000ms for *both* delays, the duty cycle is [only] 50% for output, so the 7 segment display will probably flicker badly.

That's because, when in tristate/input mode, the 7 segment display is *not* being driven with the correct segment mask/output value

The solution is to increase the duty cycle to (e.g.) 99.44% [the purity of Ivory Soap :-)]. So, *most* of the time, the port is in output mode. We only enter tristate/input mode *briefly* to sample the [DIP switch] input pins.

Here's a refactored version that keeps the port in output mode a high percentage of the time:

```
// NOTE: these may be need to be adjusted
enum {
    INPUT_STABILIZE_DELAY =     1,      // as short as possible
    OUTPUT_STABILIZE_DELAY =    1,      // as short as possible
    OUTPUT_HOLD_DELAY =         100,    // as long as possible
};

void
main()
{

    while (true) {
        // set port B lower four bits for input
        SET_TRIS_B(0b00001111);

        // allow port to stabilize
        delay_ms(INPUT_STABILIZE_DELAY);

        // get input and mask off don't care bits
        DSPIN = input_b();
        DSPIN &= 0b00001111;

        // set output mode based on input
        if ((DSPIN >= 0b00000000) && (DSPIN <= 0b00001111))
            DSPOUT = DSPIN;
        else
            DSPOUT = 0;

        // set port B pins for output
        SET_TRIS_B(0b00000000);

        // allow tristate pins to stabilize
        delay_ms(OUTPUT_STABILIZE_DELAY);

        // output to 7 segment delay
        output_b(DSPVALOR[DSPOUT]);

        // ensure that port is in output mode 99.44% of the time
        delay_ms(OUTPUT_HOLD_DELAY);
    }
}
```